# Phonegap iOS device.uuid is undefined

Tags: cordova

I have the following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
    element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                       'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                       'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
</body>
```

but my iPhone 4S shows only the "Loading device properties..." text.

Is it another issue with the Corova.plist? I am developing it on windows and I cannot set it in visual editor and I could not find any documentation for its format and possibilities.

Comment: Not sure maybe your SDK version is too old. IOS changes something from IOS 5 to 6 AFIK that breaks old code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the sample ondeviceready handler in the documentation

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

They use

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

with

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Try setting up your event handler in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "device" from ids in html.